# General Purpose GUI for SSH Logins

Tags: gui, ssh

Does an application that supplies a general purpose GUI to all SSH logins from the cmdline exist?

I notice that people are not always good at using the cmdline and think this would be a good tool. Also, simply using some remote desktop application is not always feasible as, in my experience, servers don't supply a GUI.

I wanted to ask this question before creating anything of the sort.

EDIT:
I know there are file transfer applications that enable this use (WinSCP, filezilla, etc.), but I was wondering if there was a more general purpose application that existed that provided minimum read, write, and execute operations on the data (like any file system on a host OS). Once the client interacts with the server, I would want a user to have a window that they can see file icons (read and write data).

Comment: If you don't like command line you can always install the various X libraries and such and whatever GUI applications you want and tunnel X clients over ssh to a local-to-you X server ...   otherwise, I have no idea as to what a GUI app would do as a replacement for command line...

Comment: @ivanivan Cool, thanks for your reply! Mostly, it would be nice for a person to do what they do on regular machines: read, write, and execute files. Using the cmdline can be slow for some people (I'm a CS major and like using it), so I think it'd be helpful. I'll check out your suggestion and see what I can find.

Comment: Which operating system? Must it be [tag:gratis], or do you have a budget? Welcome aboard, but please read [ask]

Comment: The idea is that a) it provides minimum read, write, and execute operations on the data. Just like any GUI for a file system. OS or whether it is free or not is not important, and thus is not a part of my question. I am only concerned if there is an existence of such a product for the purposes of creating my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want file system like access, on a *nix system you can use `sshfs` and mount a remote file system and the various GUI file managers, application based file-pickers ("open file..." "save as..." etc) all see it as just another directory on the tree.  A quick google shows Win10 supporting it as well. http://makerlab.cs.hku.hk/index.php/en/mapping-network-drive-over-ssh-in-windows

The ultimate in GUI access to remote files via ssh though is to simply tunnel X over the ssh connection and use a local to you X sever for the remote running X clients.

Answer (score 1):

You want [PuTTY - World's Most Popular Free SSH Client](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). It’s the only SSH GUI I have ever used in industry.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) :

> PuTTY (/ˈpʌti/) is a free and open-source terminal emulator, serial console and network file transfer application. It supports several network protocols, including SCP, SSH, Telnet, rlogin, and raw socket connection. It can also connect to a serial port. The name "PuTTY" has no official meaning.
>
> PuTTY was originally written for Microsoft Windows, but it has been ported to various other operating systems. Official ports are available for some Unix-like platforms, with work-in-progress ports to Classic Mac OS and macOS, and unofficial ports have been contributed to platforms such as Symbian, Windows Mobile and Windows Phone.

Read more [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/), and Windows specific stuff (since you don’t state an o/s, but did mention Winsftp) [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added in the question more of what I am looking for. Mainly a minimum read, write, and execute operations on the data -- like a file system that the user can interact with. PuTTY only SSHs into the client. Once the client interacts with the server, I would want a user to have a window that they can see file icons (read and write data).